# Unexisting class referred in the JDK library (sun.awt.image.URLImageSource)

Tags: java

is it possible that Oracle (or Sun) has taken any classes out of the Java library and the other classes are still referring those abandoned classes?

I mean, just run this code in your environment:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    URL url = new URL("http://i.imgur.com/5a5znrs.jpg");
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    Object content = con.getContent();
    String className = content.getClass().getCanonicalName();
    System.out.println(className);
}
```

You'll see `sun.awt.image.URLImageSource` but I guess there's no such a class in your library too, and there's no way that you can deal with the returned content.

Can anybody tell me where the class is?

Comment: Works fine here. What version of Java are you using and what OS?

Comment: Hi Daemon, do you really have sun.awt.image.URLImageSource class in your library? My PC is on Win7 and my JDK is 1.7.

Comment: *"is it possible that Oracle (or Sun) has taken any classes out of the Java library"* - Yes, that's why `sun.*` is considered a private API

Comment: I didn't know of private APIs... thank you MadProgrammer

Comment: If I am not mistaken when they do an update to their private API's the are included in an update log somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bet you are using an implementation of JDK that does not contain sun libraries (like OpenJDK, JRockit?).

Comment: is "Java SE Development Kit 7u45" OpenJDK?

Comment: @RyoichiroOka No, that's Oracle JDK.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever changes Oracle team does to non-public API classes it cannot affect public API classes behavior